# microsoft access - extract meta data

Tags: ms-access-2007, metadata

is it possible to access meta data from a Microsoft mdb? We have many mdb files and would like to know which files are used in each. Is this data accessible programmatically or with special utility?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what kind of metadata you want to read from the files.

Comment: tables used, field names, dump of queries etc... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata